# how to print multiple location google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

`onCreate` method:

```
{
        double[] lat = {24.8926596, 48.85837, 0};
        double[] lang = {67.0835093, 2.294481, 0};
        List<CustomberLatLang> list = new ArrayList<CustomberLatLang>();
        CustomberLatLang datamodel = new CustomberLatLang();
        for (int i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {
            datamodel.setLat(lat[i]);
            datamodel.setLang(lang[i]);
            list.add(datamodel);

        }
        insertMarkers(list);
}
```

`insertMarkers` method:

```
 private void insertMarkers(List<CustomberLatLang> list) {
        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            final LatLng position = new LatLng(list.get(i).getLat(), list.get(i).getLang());
            final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(position);

            map.addMarker(options);

            builder.include(position);
        }

    }
```

Datamodel:

```
public class CustomberLatLang {

    double lat;
    double lang;

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(double lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }
}
```

I am trying to set marker of all Location google map. When i try to run my code then i am getting `nullpointer exception map.addMarker(options);`

Comment: check logcat output and post it here!

Comment: Null Pointer Exception at line   map.addMarker(options);

Comment: can u please tell me where am doing wrong @PareshMayani

Comment: Your `map` variable is null. Post the code where you declare/init it.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/R852HXrdrMKqeaLvsEpjyk  look whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `map` variable is null. Try to init this variable before using.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    map = fm.getMap();

    ...
    insertMarkers(list);
```

Comment: Where do you call `insertMarkers` method?

Comment: Try to place `map = fm.getMap();` **before** calling `insertMarkers`

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple markers on your GoogleMap using this --

```
try {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        Origin_Map = extras.getString(MainActivity.ORIGIN_MAP);
        Destination_Map = extras.getString(MainActivity.DESTINATION_MAP);
        Addr_Origin = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Origin_Map, 1);
        Addr_Dest = geocoder.getFromLocationName(Destination_Map, 1);
        if (Addr_Origin.size() > 0) {
            latitude_origin = Addr_Origin.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude_origin = Addr_Origin.get(0).getLongitude();
        }
        if (Addr_Dest.size() > 0) {
            latitude_destination = Addr_Dest.get(0).getLatitude();
            longitude_destination = Addr_Dest.get(0).getLongitude();
        }
        Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude_origin, longitude_origin)).title(Origin_Map).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        Marker m2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude_destination, longitude_destination)).title(Destination_Map).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting the names of two locations from another activity and marking them in the GoogleMap, which is already initialized separately.

EDITED SECTION::

To initialize the Map, use the following --

```
private void initializeMap()
{
    if (googleMap == null) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: same thing i did but its show Error at Line  map.addMarker(markerOptions);

Comment: What is the error? Did you get the Latitude and the Longitude correctly?

Comment: Is your Map initialized? If not, then you can check my edited section and then call the `addMarker`.